# Encrypting a connection string in memory using a class

Tags: c#, class, encryption

I am writing a Windows Service using C# and .Net 4.6.  The service is configured such that it runs perpetually by sleeping for a configurable period of time, before running and performing some tasks.  As part of the initial start-up, the service goes and gets a list of connection strings so it can connect to a list of database servers and gather some information.  I want to be able to persist the connection strings in memory.  The idea is that the service grabs the connection strings on startup and holds them in memory until the service stops.  Next time it starts it goes and grabs them again.  This has led me down the path of encrypting the connection strings as some may contain username/password combinations.

So What  I have tried to do it create a class to store this information, and handle the encryption/decryption of the connection string on the fly with the get and set properties.

Note:  I have hard-coded a length of the byte array to 1024, but this should probably be dynamically adjusted to the nearest 16.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace XXXXXXX.DB
{
    public class Instance
    {

        private byte[] _connectionString = new byte[1024];
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ae = new ASCIIEncoding();
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            set
            {
                if (value.Length < _connectionString.Length)
                    value = value.PadRight(_connectionString.Length, ' ');
                else
                    value = value.Substring(0, _connectionString.Length);

                _connectionString = ae.GetBytes(value);
                ProtectedMemory.Protect(_connectionString, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);

            }

            get
            {
                ProtectedMemory.Unprotect(_connectionString, MemoryProtectionScope.SameProcess);
                return ae.GetString(_connectionString).Trim();
            }

        }

    }
```

So I set the ConnectionString property on an Instance object and it is encrypted as I expect.  But when I access the unencrypted ConnectionString, the result is still encrypted:

`using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_theInstance.ConnectionString))`

I think this is the fact that the private member variable for ConnectionString is a byte array which is a reference type?  To be honest I'm scratching my head a bit on this.

**Please note** I've looked at many, many examples that make a simple console app and do the encryption and unencrypted all in the same method - but can it be done as I'm trying to do?

Comment: Keeping things encrypted in memory without leaking any unencrypted copies of it is 1) very hard to do correctly in managed code and 2) something that's really only worth doing for the most sensitive of data that really needs all the protection it can get, like the private part of an encryption key that's used a lot. For anything slightly below that (including passwords in connection strings) relying on the OS security to keep your machine and the memory of the process safe is good enough and the rest would be make-believe.

Comment: For starters, `SqlConnection` makes no attempt whatsoever to keep anything safe. The instant you have to decrypt the string and pass it off to the constructor, it's there, unencrypted, floating around in the managed heap, and probably as multiple copies (if my vague memory of the internals serves me), but certainly by the time the TDS code needs to step in and actually use the password. And these unencrypted copies may persist for the entire rest of your application's lifetime.

Comment: There is `System.SecureString` that aims to minimize the lifetime of the string, but even Microsoft recommend not using it anymore because it gives a false sense of security when in practice the benefits are small.

Comment: OK, so essentially what I'm reading is I'm probably wasting my time trying to encrypt/decrypt when there are parts of the application that have the unencrypted information anyhow.   It seemed like a good idea based on the MS examples.. who would have thought!

Comment: Even Microsoft's toy examples typically fail to take into account the possibility of unmanaged buffers of unencrypted data existing before the application ever gets to it; they have to assume that *if* all the paths before resulted in no way for the unencrypted data to leak, *then* the sample would at least not introduce more opportunities for leaking -- but often the race is lost either just before or just after it's run. Securely processing encrypted data means *everything* that touches the data unencrypted must be aware of what it's doing.

Comment: I agree with Jeroen here. If you do anything, then try and minimize access to the (running) application and its memory. That's better than trying to secure something for which security was never considered.